# I'm trying to translation display property with css but I failed

Tags: html, css, transition

I'm trying to translation display property with css but I failed. I wan't to transition display property for 3 second but Its doesn't work.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}

.container:hover {
  display: flex;
  transition: display 3s;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The display property can't be "transitioned".

Comment: let's suppose you can do such transition how it should work? anyone can imagine their own animation

Comment: See the list of what can be transited http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/